# Stabilising feet for HP rack

Tags: rack

I have inherited a HP 10636 G2 42U rack and I'm trying to work out the stabilising feet. Here's a photo of one of the corners (the castor is visible behind the metal bracket): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilpKA.jpg

The feet only unscrew about half way down to the floor so I'm assuming that I'm missing a piece. I've checked the user manual and I can't find any references to stabilising feet, nor can I find any info online.

Am I missing some equipment?

Comment: Just an off the wall question. How do you know that bolt is to stabilize the rack?

Comment: I don't! It was just a guess :)